# Unauthorized controller method detected by a bot in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

Through my application log, I have noticed the following HttpException has been raised:

> *"A public action method 'MyMethod' was not found on controller 'MyApp.Controllers.MyController'"*
>
> *Controller: "MyController", Action: "MyAction" (GET)*

This is normal because *MyAction* is a **POST** method.
But *MyController* can be accessed by **authenticated users only**, thanks to a controller filter overriding HandleUnauthorizedRequest() method.
Moreover, *MyAction* is called by Ajax from a Scripts file dedicated to authenticated functionalities.

(Please note that *MyAction* and *MyController* are not the real names, I have changed them here, and they  are absolutely uncommon names which cannot be guessed without reading the JS file.)

I fear for my application security.
How is this possible that the existence of this controller method has been detected by an unauthentified user (which is a bot according to its IP address location)? What should I do to avoid that issue?

Comment: "uncommon names which cannot be guess without reading the JS file" Sounds to me like someone read the JS file. You can't really rely on obscure naming to keep hackers off your endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't rely on obscure namings, I just explain that it can't be a coincidence. The JS file is used by authenticated users only. How can a bot access it?